# How to detect Ethereum ERC721 token

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have read the [article](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/165) abount ERC165 that is enable us to detect which interface is implemented in a contract.

However,  I found that some ERC721 tokens are a little bit diffrent from others, like [cryptokitties](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d) and [cryptohorse](http://www.cryptohorse.ch/sourceC.html).

Are these different ERC721 tokens are both detected as erc721 token by wallet application.

And how does erc721 support wallet detect the type of tokens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs @ https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, ok, I ask this question in ethereum.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, some ERC-721 contracts do not follow the standard. The reason for most of them is because they were deployed before the ERC-721 standard was actually confirmed. One of these examples is CryptoKitties.

Use ERC-721 Validator that checks if a smart contract fully follows the ERC-721 standard: https://erc721validator.org

Answer (score 1):

In golang you can detect if a contract is a token by calling the EVM and checking the output, kind of like this:

```
// Getting token Decimals 
input, err = erc20_token_abi.Pack("decimals")
if err!=nil {
    utils.Fatalf("packing input for decimals failed: %v",err)
}
msg=types.NewMessage(fake_src_addr,addr,0,value,gas_limit,gas_price,input,false)
evm_ctx=core.NewEVMContext(msg,block_header,chain,nil)
ethvirmac=vm.NewEVM(evm_ctx,statedb,bconf,vm_cfg)
gp=new(core.GasPool).AddGas(math.MaxBig256)
ret,gas,failed,err=core.ApplyMessage(ethvirmac,msg,gp)
tok.decimals_found=false
if (failed) {
    log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("vm err for decimals: %v, failed=%v",err,failed))
}
if err!=nil {
    log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("getting 'decimals' caused error in vm: %v",err))
}
if !((err!=nil) || (failed)) {
    int_output:=new(uint8)
    err=erc20_token_abi.Unpack(int_output,"decimals",ret)
    if err!=nil {
        log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Contract %v: can;t upack decimals: %v",hex.EncodeToString(addr.Bytes()),err))
    } else {
        tok.decimals=int32(*int_output)
        tok.decimals_found=true
    }
}
```

But if you don't want to get your hands dirty by working with the EVM directly, you can check event signatures:

```
erc20_approval_signature,_ = hex.DecodeString("8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925")
erc20_transfer_signature,_ = hex.DecodeString("ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef")
```

These are located at event.Topics[0], so if Topics[0] matches to the above string the probability that the contract is ERC20 token is high. If you collect all the event of a contract, and derive a summary of what methods does it use, you can decide either it is a ERC20 or ERC721